# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Не нужно ли добавить двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Зашел в супермаркет, запасся продовольствием и, напевая мысленно «А я ежиков люблю…», отправился вперед.

Answer (score 2):

Такое оформление допускается правилами, в приведенном примере  дословное высказывание играет роль дополнения.

Розенталь http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm

Примечание. Подлинные выражения, вставленные в текст **в качестве элементов предложения,** выделяются кавычками, **но перед ними двоеточие не ставится**, например: Это **«не хочу»** поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Гоголь); Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», все больше собирало сторонников (Фадеев); Он вспомнил пословицу **«Не плюй в колодец...»** и отошел в сторону; С криком **«Спасайте детей!»** юноша бросился в горящее здание.